# How to obtain a non-auto updating result set in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm's [`RLMResults`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.89.2/api/Classes/RLMResults.html) is an auto-updating container. Typically, auto-updating is a great thing, but I'm struggling with it for a specific application:

I'm sending up arrays of model objects to the server, and then deleting them from Realm if the send was successful. Since this can happen concurrently, each model has a `currentlyProcessing` attribute. I use `objectsWhere()` with a predicate querying for unprocessed objects, set them to processing, and then aim to delete those same objects. Since the RLMResults container is auto-updating, the original `unprocessedObjects` RLMResults is empty, deleting that specific set isn't straightforward.

Is there any way to turn off the auto-update? Or make an immutable copy of an `RLMResults`?

Comment: This is a major limitation of Realm. My previous use didn't require it, but ATM I'm VERY frustrated with this. Copying into an `RLMArray` isn't a solution for me, because I need to be able to re-filter/query again later.

Comment: Exact same problem here: I want to download profile picture on the fly a cache them in an ignored property. Since RLMResults auto-reload the image is never cached. If I store the image in a not ignored NSData the entire list will reload and other images will be downloaded twice... This limitation is very frustrating and I wonder if I should fallback on coredata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, there's no way to get a 'frozen' `RLMResults`, but [support is forthcoming](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1179). Your best bet will be to copy your objects out of that results into an array.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The link in this answer doesn't apply to this issue. It appears to be more about how the auto-updating should be turned off during fast-enumeration. I too would like a way to turn off the auto-update.

Comment: @livingtech as the link (and other issues state) theres no way to disable autoupdating (which we also call freezing)

Comment: I read through the commentary on that one issue, and it does not state clearly that support for freezing is coming as a feature. Would love to be wrong about this though... sounds like you have some insider knowledge?

Comment: Yes, I work on Realm. I can confirm we will support frozen results at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it didn't work for me to use an array (`RLMArray` or `NSArray`), because I needed to make further sub-selects later, so I ended up with the following solution (which relies on my identifier property):

```
RLMResult *result = ...
NSMutableArray *ids = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:results.count];
for (MyObj *obj in results)
{
    [ids addObject:obj.identifier];
}
results = [MyObj objectsWhere:@"identifier IN %@", ids];
```